# axiom of regularity and its consequence $A\bigcap \{A\}=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

> every non-empty set $A$ contains an element that is disjoint from $A$

> No set can be an element of itself

The second statement is the consequence of the first statement, but I cannot get it.

**Under Elementary implications of regularity in the link, there is a saying $A\bigcap\{A\}=\emptyset$, we cannot have $A\in A$**

I understand the statement separately or I know they are wrong in the set theory, of course, $A\notin A$, but I don't see the implication.

[axiom of regularity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Axiom_of_regularity#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20axiom%20of,that%20is%20disjoint%20from%20A.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which elements does $\{A\}$ have?

Comment: I've removed the `real analysis` tag since it is out ouf context

Comment: @AsafKaragila simply just say let $A$ be a set in wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then there is no $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Hence, if $A\cap \{A\}=\varnothing$, there is no $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\in\{A\}$. If it were the case that $A\in A$, then there would be an $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\in \{A\}$, namely $A$.